Improving prunus germination
Whenever I eat stone fruit from my garden or the farmer's market, I toss the pits in a big planter. The planter is protected from rodents with 1/4-inch mesh and insulated with leaves over winter.
Normally, I get hundreds of seedlings from the pits the next year. But this year, I only got a couple dozen. That's surprising because it was a mild winter. Should I be doing something differently to get better germination?

Zone 6, east of Toronto
The area is sheltered on all sides by walls and fences; damp & shaded




Related: North American Fruit Explorers - NAFEX

Its probably beacause it was a mild winter, and the seeds didnt get enough cold stratification to enduce germination. so youre not doing anything wrong, the seeds benifit from colder weather.
you could put them in a refridgerator for a few weeks or all winter, before planting them out in time for spring.
